# Is there a way to increment index of *ngFor outside the loop?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have to read an array and display it in two columns.
I searched through Internet and the only things I found were just how to get index, is index odd or even. But it won't work for me because if I do, for example, check for isEven on first column and isOdd on second, first column will show some values, second is empty, then first is empty, second will have data and so on.

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let provider of providers; let isOdd = odd; let isEven = even;">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <template [ngIf]="isEven">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <label class="col-xs-6"><b>{{'company' | translate | capitalize}}</b></label>
                    <label class="col-xs-6">{{provider.name}}</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <label class="col-xs-6"><b>{{'type' | translate | capitalize}} </b></label>
                    <label class="col-xs-6">{{provider.type.providerTypeName}}</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <label class="col-xs-6"><b>{{'whatwedo' | translate | capitalize}}</b></label>
                    <label class="col-xs-6">{{provider.description}}</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <label class="col-xs-6"><b>{{ 'periodicity' | translate | capitalize }}</b></label>
                    <label class="col-xs-6">{{provider.periodicity | translate | capitalize}}</label>
                </div>
                <address>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <label class="col-xs-6"><b>{{ 'phone' | translate | capitalize}}</b></label>
                        <label class="col-xs-6">{{provider.phone}}</label>
                    </div>
                </address>

                <address>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <label class="col-xs-6"><b>{{ 'email' | translate | capitalize}}</b></label>
                        <label class="col-xs-6"><a href="mailto:#">{{provider.email}}</a></label>
                    </div>
                </address>
                <address>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <label class="col-xs-6"><b>{{ 'address' | translate | capitalize }}</b></label>
                        <label class="col-xs-6">{{provider.address}}</label>
                    </div>
                </address>

                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <label class="col-xs-6"><b>{{'schedule' | translate | capitalize }}</b></label>
                    <label class="col-xs-6">{{provider.schedule}}</label>
                </div>

                <div class="right">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['.', provider.providerId]"> {{'providergo' | translate
                        |
                        capitalize }} <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
                </div>
            </template>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <template [ngIf]="isOdd">

                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <label class="col-xs-6"><b>{{'company' | translate | capitalize}}</b></label>
                    <label class="col-xs-6">{{provider.name}}</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <label class="col-xs-6"><b>{{'type' | translate | capitalize}} </b></label>
                    <label class="col-xs-6">{{provider.type.providerTypeName}}</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <label class="col-xs-6"><b>{{'whatwedo' | translate | capitalize}}</b></label>
                    <label class="col-xs-6">{{provider.description}}</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <label class="col-xs-6"><b>{{ 'periodicity' | translate | capitalize }}</b></label>
                    <label class="col-xs-6">{{provider.periodicity | translate | capitalize}}</label>
                </div>
                <address>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <label class="col-xs-6"><b>{{ 'phone' | translate | capitalize}}</b></label>
                        <label class="col-xs-6">{{provider.phone}}</label>
                    </div>
                </address>

                <address>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <label class="col-xs-6"><b>{{ 'email' | translate | capitalize}}</b></label>
                        <label class="col-xs-6"><a href="mailto:#">{{provider.email}}</a></label>
                    </div>
                </address>
                <address>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <label class="col-xs-6"><b>{{ 'address' | translate | capitalize }}</b></label>
                        <label class="col-xs-6">{{provider.address}}</label>
                    </div>
                </address>

                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <label class="col-xs-6"><b>{{'schedule' | translate | capitalize }}</b></label>
                    <label class="col-xs-6">{{provider.schedule}}</label>
                </div>

                <div class="right">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['.', provider.providerId]"> {{'providergo' | translate
                        |
                        capitalize }} <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
                </div>
            </template>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is there a way to do what I want? Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you care about where the items fall in terms of columns or do you just want 2 columns?

Comment: I just want 2 columns with distinct values

Comment: hmm, I would try grabbing the the loop index with `let i = index` and then  write value to the first columns until i > 1/2 of the list and then write values to the second list. This would require knowing the length of the list, which you can bind to property in the component.

Comment: so `[ngiF]="i > listLength"` for the first column and `[ngIF]="i < listLength"` for the second column.

Comment: it finally works, thank you for your help. But to make it work I should have added loops in both of columns. And then check length of array in ngIf